# custom cutter has invalid Lhs or Rhs

Tags: python, scip, simplex-algorithm, pyscipopt

I'm trying to write a custom separator (aka, MIP cutter) to my SCIP model (in Python). To do this I need to detect which constraints are tight/binding at the given MIP node. I thought that I could do this by comparing LHS to RHS on the rows (aka, the constraints). However, one of the two always reports +/- 1e20. Why is that? How do I iterate on the binding constraints?

```py
    class Cutter(scip.Sepa):
        def sepaexeclp(self):
            m: scip.Model = self.model
            if not m.getLPSolstat() or not m.isLPSolBasic():
                return {"result": scip.PY_SCIP_RESULT.DIDNOTRUN}
        
            cols = m.getLPColsData()
            rows = m.getLPRowsData()
        
            values = [col.getPrimsol() for col in cols]
            constraints = [row for row in rows if row.getLhs() == row.getRhs()]  # always empty
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding. All rows in SCIP are ranged rows, i.e., they are of the form `lhs <= a^Tx (+constant) <= rhs`. When a model contains inequalities with only one side (as seems to be the case for you) then the non-existant side is set to either `1e20` for the rhs (SCIPs infinity value) or `-1e20` for the lhs.

I'm assuming what you really want to do is check which constraints are tight w.r.t. the current LP at that node? In that case you should use `getRowActivity`